# React text input with numerals only

Tags: reactjs

I've been trying a few ways to adjust react text input to write numerals only, but I don't get the results that fit. Right now I'm using this and it works, until I want to delete the number and I can't do that because there must be a number and I can't leave an empty input. Any other ways to check if the inserted input value is a number?

```
const [limit, setLimit] = useState("");

function handleChange (e) {
        let value = e.target.value;
        if (!Number(value)) {
            return;
        }
        setLimit(e.target.value);
    }

<input type="text" name="settime" value={limit} onChange={handleChange} />
```

edit: Completely by accident solved the problem, here's the function:

```
function handleChange (e) {

        if (limit === 0) {
            setLimit(null);
        }
        let value = e.target.value
        if (Number(value) || value === "") {
            setLimit(e.target.value);
        } else {
            return
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried `type="number"`

Comment: I did try input type number, but you can still write letters there. Not an option.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `type="number"` to fix it:

```
<input type="number" name="settime" value={limit} onChange={handleChange} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use input type number ,for using number values

`<input type="number" name="settime" value={limit} onChange={handleChange} />`

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It might solve your issue :

`<input type="number" name="settime" value={limit} onChange={handleChange} />`

User will not be able to type letters :)
More reading:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number

Answer (score 0):

In your onChange handler, if you get a non-number, use `setLimit` anyways to set a blank

```
if (!Number(value)) {
    setLimit("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use isNan().

```
if(isNaN(value)){
   return;
}
setLimit(value)
```